# Categorical variables not displaying correctly in summary of data

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to do some data analysis for a statistics assignment. And when I try to look at a summary of my data, the categorical variables do not display correctly. This is what I see when I run my code:

[image: This is what I see when I run my code.]

vs what is shown when my lecturer runs the same code:

[image: VS What is shown when my lecturer runs the same code.]

This is the code that I am using, copied directly from my lecturers notes.

```
stormwater <- read.csv("stormwater example Milandri et al.csv")
head(stormwater)
tail(stormwater)
summary(stormwater)
```

Comment: Because you are on R 4.0.0 I guess and your lecturer is on R < 4.0.0 where `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default in `read.csv`. Add `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in your `read.csv` and you should get same results.

Comment: @Ronak, post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes because of different R versions. You are on R 4.0.0 (or higher) where `stringsAsFactors` default value is changed to `FALSE` so all your string data is read as characters instead of factors which was default in previous versions.

You should get the same result as your lecturer if you add  `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in your `read.csv` command.

```
stormwater <- read.csv("stormwater example Milandri et al.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
summary(stormwater)
```